# How to visualize interaction with other variables controlled?

Tags: data-visualization, interaction

We want to visualize the relationship between y (continuous), x (continuous), and treatment (two groups A and B). One way of doing this is plot y~x, with treatment group shown as two series / colors. This should demonstrate the interaction between x and treatment on y.

Now, Let's say we have a regression model:

y = intercept + a * Treatment + b * Covariates + c * x + d * x*Treatment

My question is, how to visualize the relationship of y, x, and treatment, with the covariates considered?

Comment: Where is x and the interaction term in your formula?

Comment: I want to visualize it, not to calculate it in regression, that will be easy. Do I need to include it in the model for purpose of visualization?

Comment: You can consider making a margin plot. It will have the same components of your suggested graph, but it will reflect the proper a, b, and d with x adjusted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it is what I wanted. In SAS term, it should be lsmeans plot. https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glimmix_a0000001478.htm

Comment: `lsmeans` may work, also check out the `estimate` option.